# How to update PySpark df on the basis of other PySpark df?

Tags: python, pyspark

```
df1
+------------------------------------------------------
|ID|  NAME|ADDRESS|DELETE_FLAG|INSERT_DATE|UPDATE_DATE|
+------------------------------------------------------
| 1|sravan|delhi  |false      |25/01/2023 |25/01/2023|
| 2|ojasvi|patna  |false      |25/01/2023 |25/01/2023|
| 3|rohith|jaipur |false      |25/01/2023 |25/01/2023|

df2
+----------
|ID|  NAME|
+----------
| 1|sravan|
| 2|ojasvi|
```

Suppose I have two pyspark df's (df1 and df2)

How can I get the result df3 like below given ID and NAME are the keys?

```
df3
    +------------------------------------------------------
    |ID|  NAME|ADDRESS|DELETE_FLAG|INSERT_DATE|UPDATE_DATE|
    +------------------------------------------------------
    | 1|sravan|delhi  |true       |25/01/2023 |02/02/2023|
    | 2|ojasvi|patna  |true       |25/01/2023 |02/02/2023|
    | 3|rohith|jaipur |false      |25/01/2023 |25/01/2023|
```

I am looking more for a generic answer where I state the keys within a list or store it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired results by doing something like this,

```
# List of keys on which the join should happen
keys = ['ID', 'NAME']

df1_cols = [f"a.{i}" for i in df1.columns]

# Use 'inner' as it only gives you records that are present in both and select only the columns from left df as that is what we want
delete_records = df1.alias('a').join(df2.alias('b'), keys, 'inner').select(*df1_cols)

# Set all the flags to True as they are deleted
delete_records = delete_records.withColumn('DELETE_FLAG', F.lit('true'))

print("Deleted records:")
delete_records.show(truncate=False)

# First remove the older records from df1 matched with delete records and then upsert them into df1, optional but if you want yo can use orderBy to keep the order according to the keys.
df1 = df1.join(delete_records, keys, 'anti').union(delete_records).orderBy(keys)

print("Updated DF1:")
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
Deleted records:
+---+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|ID |NAME  |ADDRESS|DELETE_FLAG|INSERT_DATE|UPDATE_DATE|
+---+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1 |sravan|delhi  |true       |25/01/2023 |25/01/2023 |
| 2 |ojasvi|patna  |true       |25/01/2023 |25/01/2023 |
+---+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+

Updated DF1:
+---+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|ID |NAME  |ADDRESS|DELETE_FLAG|INSERT_DATE|UPDATE_DATE|
+---+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1 |sravan|delhi  |true       |25/01/2023 |25/01/2023 |
| 2 |ojasvi|patna  |true       |25/01/2023 |25/01/2023 |
| 3 |rohith|jaipur |false      |25/01/2023 |25/01/2023 |
+---+------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```